# mysql server rejected the connection php admin requested

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm rather new to PHP and xampp.
I am using my computer for developing java and php now.
So I have a mysql server installed in my computer already.
I installed xampp successfully. But when I'm trying to access phpMyAdmin, it gives me an error saying

```
mysql server rejected the connection php admin requested
```

(this not the actual error, but this is what it means..)

I tried stopping my current MySQL service and installing it again.
I tried configuring config.inc.php which I think is the way do this.
But I couldn't do much with that.

Can anyone tell me how to configure and use my computer for php developing keeping my current mysql server unchanged.

thank you.

PS: There is no problem with my current mysql server.It's working fine.
Problem there is I cant use it with phpmyadmin which i installed with Xampp.
I think it is because Xampp have its own mysql server buldled with it and phpmyadmin configured to use it.
That's the problem.

**I want to use my current mysql server insted of the one bundled with xampp.**

Comment: What is the actual error message? Are you able to log in to the MySQL server from the command line?

Comment: Please paste the actual error and its error code, instead of paraphrasing what it said... it will go a long way towards us figuring out what the problem is!

Comment: +1 for trying via command line. Since the mysql server is local we can rule out `bind-address`, and if you can't `mysql -u root -p`, then the root account's password is just wrong.

Comment: There is no problem with my current MySQL server.
I can log in and do everything.
Problem is I can't use it with phpmyadmin

Comment: try using hints given here http://www.apachefriends.org/en/faq-xampp-windows.html#ownmysql

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully resolved my problem.
I stopped my current mysql service and installed xampp.
Don't forget to uncheck where it ask you to install services on insallation wizard.
And then I started mysql service which was installed already.
and edit **config.inc.php** as below..

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config'

to

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'

and you will be prompted to give your current password and username at phpmyadmin login..

**Thank you for all guys who tried to help me..**